# Code sign exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, code-signing

I'm trying to upload my iphone application to app store and I followed all the steps that developer program page has in it, and no matter what I change I always get the same exception which is "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1", I'm developing on xcode 4.1, the build log is the next bellow:

```
CodeSign build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app
cd /Users/yyyy/Documents/xxxx
 PATH  "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: xxxx LLC" --resource-  rules=/Users/yyyy/Documents/xxxx/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app/ResourceRules.plist --    entitlements /Users/booksprice/Documents/xxxx/build/xxxx.build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.build/xxxx.xcent /Users/yyyy/Documents/xxxx/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app

/Users/yyyy/Documents/xxxx/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxx.app: The operation was  cancelled by the user.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this SO question: [codesign "The operation was cancelled by the user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062285/codesign-the-operation-was-cancelled-by-the-user) ? Sounds like restarting your Mac and unlocking your keychain helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079422/i-have-a-error-while-running-my-iphone-application-in-ipod-device-what-to-do

Comment: i Have question: codesign "The operation was cancelled by the user" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop on Xcode 4, but you should be submitting your application with Xcode 3.2.5.