# iOS distribution Certificates disappear and i can not update app

Tags: ios, certificate

My iOS distribution Certificates disappear on apple developer web,and I do not have a copy on local.
Then i new a  iOS distribution certificates and Provisioning Profiles,but xcode remind me must use the old certificates .
[image]

So I can not update my app on AppStore.
How I can do now?

Comment: I solve it by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062285/codesign-the-operation-was-cancelled-by-the-user

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 8 than just enable the **"Automatic manage signing"** at project settings general tab, and Xcode will handle all signing related stuff. Check Attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help