# Build on device fails with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I build an app successfully. After changing a bit, the build and run on simulator works still fine as expected, but the build and run with my physical device fails unexpected:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Intermediates/WhagooAppFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/WhagooAppFramework.build/Script-26D4B954E53A2CB72C219E1A.sh
>       cd "/Users/oliverapel/Dropbox/WhaGoO/Project WhaGoO/App.iOS/development"
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Intermediates/WhagooAppFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/WhagooAppFramework.build/Script-26D4B954E53A2CB72C219E1A.sh
>
> mkdir -p /Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BerlinCapitalClub.app/Frameworks
>   rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BerlinCapitalClub.app/Frameworks"
>   building file list ... done
>   Alamofire.framework/
>
> sent 147 bytes  received 26 bytes  346.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 1073519  speedup is 6205.31
>   Code Signing /Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BerlinCapitalClub.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Oliver Apel (W65P7YG9ZK)
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign B68B8D50CF4B9D2517527291D6F3D051423B194F  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BerlinCapitalClub.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework"
>   /Users/oliverapel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhagooAppFramework-ckcaymayjufpexdicjfdawwbkeht/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BerlinCapitalClub.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: User canceled the operation.
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

In the last line I see `user canceled the operation.` but I do nothing like this.

I already cleaned build folder, removed derived data and now I don´t know what to do.

Comment: B68B8D50CF4B9D2517527291D6F3D051423B194F
This is your device UDID and i think there is something with you provising  profile . Did you added your device in your profile???

Comment: Yes I did. We have multiple devices registered and the issue comes up on all devices.

Comment: Did you add those devices in your provising profile. 
Why its showing Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks . Did you added any framework  by drag and drop in your project??

Comment: If you added any framework by drag and drop , then you must know there are 3 type of framework 1) Simulator 2) Device 3) Universal. Follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device

Comment: You might want to try this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4132121/46297

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try updating Certificates from Preference -> Accounts -> Choose developer account and Proper Team -> View Details -> Download all profiles.

Also, try doing Deep clean using Cmd+Shift+Alt+K. Make sure you have selected correct developer team in your general settings.

Also, Change Provisioning to Automatic. So that it will automatically fetch proper certificates.

After that, Goto Build Phases ->Link Binary frameworks-> Add Frameworks you want. Do this for all targets that you have.

Try this and let me know if error still occurs.

Hope it helps..

Comment: I did both but still not building :(

Answer (score 15):

lock add unlock keychain solve the problem, it' weird.

Comment: I had Keychain opened and closing it resolved my problem

Comment: That actually worked for me too, but its because the first time I archived, I denied the permission to the keystore

Comment: Yes, "me too"s are verbotten on SO, but this was such a source of confusion to me that applying this simple solution came as a great relief. Upvoted and should be checked.

Answer (score 2):

I just simply restarted my MacBook Pro. I found this solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108879).

Comment: this worked for me! It was a combination of failing signature authentication (certificates)